# How to delete a directory called ~?

Tags: linux

A defect program have created a directory called `~`.

If I do `rm \~` and then TAB it translates to `~/` which is the users home directory.

How do delete such a directory?

**Update**

See my answer that solved the problem. It is based on the posted answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
rmdir ./~
```

So, basically, you're specifying the path in such a way that there won't be shell expansion on the "~".

Answer (score 6):

Use `rmdir '~'` which should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that, and TAB rewrote it to `~/`

Comment: If you type what I wrote WITHOUT the TAB then it works. If you type what I wrote and hit TAB then it expands to `'~'/` which works. Why are you bothering with tab in this situation? What is your fascination with TAB?

Comment: Because I want to make sure that the users home directory isn't deleted.

Comment: Then don't press TAB and use '' around the ~.

Answer (score 4):

As a general answer for any file.

`ls -i`

take that number and bung it in `find -maxdepth 1 -inum [number] -exec rm -r {} \;`

Answer (score 2):

I have confirmed the following works. You can use tab completion on this as well.

```
rm ./~
```

Answer (score 1):

Without pressing tab, try

```
rmdir \~
```

Answer (score 1):

Giving the absolute path solved the problem.

```
rmdir /home/user/~
```

and TAB didn't rewrite it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

The shell performs wildcard expansion on several reserved symbols, the tilde being one example.  When the shell sees

```
$ rm ~
```

It expands the tilde to the path of the user's home directory.  Essentially, the shell 'sees' this, instead:

```
$ rm /home/$USER/
```

To prevent wildcard expansion, escape the symbol with a `\`, like so:

```
$ rm \~
```

This will ensure that the shell deals with the `~` literally.

You have two options for deleting a *directory* called `~`:

For a non-empty directory, pass the recursive flag to `rm`:

```
$ rm -r \~
```

And for an empty directory:

```
$ rmdir \~
```

Answer (score 0):

first thought would be "dont use tab" , but untested. Better option: install "mc" (midnight commander) and delete the directory from its interface. its a bit of a workaround though.